# Android Serialization/Object Passing and Returning

Tags: android, serialization, android-activity

So I have an app that manages workorders. In one part of the app, I have a list of workorders that has been retrieved from a web service. The user then picks one of the workorders from the list and the list starts a new activity (passing the Workorder object to it) that shows the workorder details. The user can edit parts of the workorder during this time. If the user returns to the list (via the back button), I need to pass the modified workorder BACK to the workorder list and either update or replace the old object with the new modified one. Otherwise, (as is currently happening) the user edits the workorder, but if they go back to the list and select the same workorder again, the workorder detail activty shows all the old data. What is the best way to do this. Currently I have the Workorder class implement Serializable so the workorder objects can be passed to successive activities.

So this works:
List -> Workorder A

But this is where I'm having the issue:
List <- Workorder A (modified)

I'm not sure if I should be using startActivtyForResult and passing the workorder object back or not. I know it's a possibility, but I'm not sure if there are more graceful ways to do this. Thanks for any and all help as it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: post your Workorder class and relevant part of the code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `Workorder` object is already `Serializable` you could easily pass the object within the [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) of an intent. To save the object to an intent you would do:

```
intent.putExtra("SomeUniqueKey", [intance of workorder]);
```

and to load in another activity:

```
Workorder workorder = (Workorder) intent.getSerializableExtra("SomeUniqueKey");
```

If you are using `startActivityForResult` it would go as such:

WorkorderListActivity.java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WorkorderDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SomeUniqueKey", _workorder);
startActivityForResult(intent, [UniqueNumber]);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
     if (requestCode == [UniqueNumber])
     {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
         {
             Workorder workorder = (Workorder) intent.getSerializableExtra("SomeUniqueKey");
             // Do whatever with the updated object
         }
     }
 }
```

WorkorderDetailsActivity.java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     _workorder = (Workorder) bundle.getSerializable("SomeUniqueKey");
     // Display the object
}

public void onBackPressed()
{
    // Update _workorder object
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.putExtra("SomeUniqueKey", _workorder);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

I believe this should work.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and see what I can do! If it works, I'll check back to mark it as answered

Comment: Quick question on this...I realized that previously I was using .putExtra("wo",wo) on the sender activity, and using .get("wo") on the receiver activity NOT .getSerializable("wo") and it was retrieving the object fine. Is that intended or was I violating some major rule?

Comment: I have never actually tried it, but I guess it makes sense that .get("wo") would work. You get back an object which at runtime is of type Serializable and setting it to your Workorder variable would automatically do a cast. As far I know, no violation there.

Comment: I just want to add that it is recommendable to refer to this serialized object with a full package, both when you set the Extra and when you get it back. Example: Workorder workorder = (Workorder) intent.getSerializableExtra("com.package.SomeUniqueKey"); and getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("com.package.SomeUniqueKey"); If your object has other nested objects, they must also implement Serializable.