# pass value from 1st to third activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle, pass-data

I have develop one android application.
Here i have to pass the value from 1st activity to third activity.

The value is passed from 1st to 2nd activity successfully developed.But i can't pass the value from 2nd to third activity.please help me how can i develop these.please help me.

This is my 1st activity:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerLogin.class);
                i.putExtra("GrandTotal", mGrandTotal);
                startActivity(i);
```

The 2nd activity:

```
Intent in = getIntent();
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String total = b.getString("GrandTotal");
TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grand_total);
 grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + total );
```

Here the value is pass from 1st to 2nd activity successfully.
Now i have to pass these value to third activity.how can i do.

Now this is my 2nd activity:

```
if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
{
    String s= getIntent().getStringExtra(total);
    Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLogin.this,PayPalIntegrationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("GrandTotal", s);
    intent.putExtra("login",username.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

This is my third activity:

```
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    String total = b.getString("GrandTotal");
    TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check);
    grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + total );
```

Now i have to run the app means am getting the total value on 2nd activity.but am not getting the total value in 3rd activity.please help me.whats am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try Log your s variable before putextra on 2nd activity, i think your s variable is null

Comment: Use Singleton class for sharing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7886046/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerLogin.class);
 i.putExtra("GrandTotal", mGrandTotal);
 startActivity(i);
```

The 2nd activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String total = b.getString("GrandTotal");
TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grand_total);
grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + total );   

  if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)  {      
      Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLogin.this,PayPalIntegrationActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("GrandTotal", total);
      intent.putExtra("login",username.getText().toString());
      startActivity(intent);    
    }
```

This is my third activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();    
String total = b.getString("GrandTotal");
String name = b.getString("login");
TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check);
grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + total );
```

Comment: the null value only displayed here from 2nd to third.this is my 2nd activity code:http://pastie.org/5561078

Comment: check ur code once "if" condition is executing  or else is executing

Comment: if condition only executed in my code.getting null on 3rda ctivity

Comment: This is my 1st activity code:http://pastie.org/5564017       This is my 2nd activity code:http://pastie.org/5564018                   This is my 3rd activity code:http://pastie.org/5564020                        please check my code and give me solution.i have changed my code.code is correct only.but am getting null value.please check it.

Comment: i have to created the String total on public.                                  total = b.getString("GrandTotal");    now i got the o/p.thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use simple static variable. Or sharedpreferences for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
{
  String s= getIntent().getStringExtra(total);// problem is here
  ....// In second activity
}
```

change to `String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("GrandTotal");`

Comment: am getting null value only from 2nd to 3rd activity.this is my 2nd activity code:pastie.org/5561078.please check my code and give me solution for these.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 if(isUserValidated && isPasswordValidated)
    {
        String s= getIntent().getStringExtra(total); // Replace this line
        Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLogin.this,PayPalIntegrationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("GrandTotal", s);
        intent.putExtra("login",username.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

with

```
String s= getIntent().getStringExtra("GrandTotal");
```

Comment: am getting null value only from 2nd to 3rd activity.this is my 2nd activity code:pastie.org/5561078.please check my code and give me solution for these.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the exact same values, you can just use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerLogin.this,PayPalIntegrationActivity.class);
intent.putextras(this.getIntent.getExtras());
```

Comment: This is simple. It is intended to be put in Activity 2. It puts the extras given from Activity 1 into the intent for Activity 3. It assumes you don't want to change the extras.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your **thired activity**

**Edit :**

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("GrandTotal")!= null)
{
      String total =getIntent().getStringExtra("GrandTotal"); <---------------
      TextView grandtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.check);
      grandtotal.setText("Welcome ," + total );
}
```

Comment: am getting null value only from 2nd to 3rd activity.this is my 2nd activity code:pastie.org/5561078.please check my code and give me solution for these.