# Android equivalent to php $_POST?

Tags: android

How to pass data from one activity to another.

Comment: Your Android application performs HTTP posts to itself?

Comment: Guys I am not looking to pass same data from one activity to other I want to submit a form with dynamic fields,number of fields will be unknown so I asked is there something equivalent to $_POST in php where on submit I can access its elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain shared preferences, use the following method In your activity:

```
SharedPreferences sp= this.getSharedPreferences("LOGINSTATUS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("counter", ++counter);
editor.commit();
```

The value for counter will get

```
SharedPreferences sp= context.getSharedPreferences("LOGINSTATUS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//-------get a value from them

String counter = sp.getString("counter", -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intent` to pass values from one `Activity` to another:

First `Activity` that calls the other:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
i.putExtra("SomeIdentifierName", myClassObj);
startActivity(i);
```

The called `Activity` gets the data via:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
MyClass myClassObj = (MyClass)i.getSerializableExtra("SomeIdentifierName");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. use `SharedPreferences` or extend `Application` class. Read more in this article - [How to share same data between multiple activities in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885276/how-to-share-same-data-between-multiple-activities-in-android)