# Pass int value from one activity to two other activities in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, bundle

I know how to pass int value from one activity to another activity(one to one).
But now I want to pass an int value to two other activities.How can I do that? I just want an idea.

Comment: There are tons of ways. Pass it with the Acitivties Intent's extras, create a singleton to manage the int, etc. Tons of ways. Google it up :)

Comment: Also, [How to share data between multiple activities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885276/how-to-share-same-data-between-multiple-activities-in-android)